# Eclipse equivalent of CTRL-K in Netbeans

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

Netbeans has a nifty shortcut completion, I use while I type. It works in comments, in strings. Pretty much places where regular completion is useless. It basically autocompletes using the editor scope (in other words, whatever word matches closes to the point you are typing). Is there something similar in Eclipse ? I am making a transition due to lack of mybatis/mylyn support in netbeans. You can read more about it here https://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/entry/why_am_i_using_netbeans .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called `Word Completion`. The key binding may vary; Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+L to find out.

Comment: Basically ALT-/ for windows 7, eclipse luna.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+Space will show and sometimes autocomplete (depends on the settings you choose) methods names, variables and etc.
You can read more about specific settings and further fine tuning [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_c_editor_con_assist.htm).